# Remove margin from text

Tags: html, css

I have a text on an image but there's a weird margin above and below the text. I tried `margin-bottom: 0;` already but that didn't do the trick.

```css
.text {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 30px;
    right: 0;        
    text-align: left;
    top: 40%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: By default h1 tag has it's own margin, you have to remove margin from h1 tag, like

`h1 {
  margin: 0;
}`

Comment: just do it `h1{all: initial}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the margin from the `h1` tag not the `div`, this is because the `h1` element has a default margin.

```css
.text {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 30px;
    right: 0;        
    text-align: left;
    top: 40%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    font-size: 75px;
}

.text h1{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Default CSS Values for HTML Elements`.
Some HTML elements comes with some default CSS properties which can sometimes result in unknown/unwanted behavior.
in this case, the `h1` element has a margin by default. you can simply set the `h1` margin to 0 or `initial`. I recommend to check this references for [the default CSS browser values for all HTML elements.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)